# OpenXml - How to remove lines between points in a scatterChart

Tags: excel, openxml

I have plotted a scatterChart in an Excel file using OpenXml. The points are joined by line. How can I remove the line? I tried doing this:

```
ScatterStyle scatterStyle = new ScatterStyle() { Val = ScatterStyleValues.Marker };
                scatterchart.AppendChild<ScatterStyle>(scatterStyle);
```

But Excel repairs the file and changes the value back to ScatterStyleValues.LineMarker from ScatterStyleValues.Marker.
Please help me. Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you have to add a shape property to your series, and add an outline where fill = nofill.
  `enter code here`

```
//ChartShapeProperty of series
ChartShapeProperties SeriesShapeProperty = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.ChartShapeProperties();
                        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Outline outline = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Outline(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.NoFill()) { Width = 28575 };
                        SeriesShapeProperty.Append(outline);
                        scatterChartSeries.Append(SeriesShapeProperty);
```